# Populate one table with data from another one on selected cells

Tags: null

I have a problem with filling empty cells in one table with data from another one.

I got a table with user emails - some of the fields are empty, some are already containing emails. I gathered the list of emails from the users who doesn't have emails in the table. I am going to import it as an separate table, and then update an exiting one. So to demonstrate:

Existing table (`USERS`):

```
ID      Email
1       aaa@bbb.com
2       NULL
3       bbb@bbb.com
4       NULL
5       NULL
```

The second table (`MYTABLE`) has exactly the same structure, but it has only `ID` and `Emails` of users who have `NULL` in original one.

I used this as a test, but find out that that code is overwriting emails if this user exist in both tables, and I don't want this:

```
UPDATE users
SET users.email = (SELECT mytable.email
                     FROM mytable
                     WHERE mytable.id = users.id)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT mytable.email
                     FROM mytable
                     WHERE mytable.id = users.id);
```

So is it possible to update ONLY cells with NULL value?

Comment: Surely as simple as adding `AND users.email IS NULL` to the where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work ;

```
UPDATE users
SET users.email = (SELECT mytable.email
                     FROM mytable
                     WHERE mytable.id = users.id)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT mytable.email
                     FROM mytable
                     WHERE mytable.id = users.id)
AND users.email IS NULL;
```